# Is trading the only way to get the MegaStones not available in my game?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have Pokemon Y and I've collected all the mega stones but I am missing the X exclusives:

- Charizardite X
- Tyranitarite
- Manectite
- Pinsirite
- Mewtwonite X

and the ORAS exclusives (if you can even get them in X/Y):

- Beedrillite
- Pidgeotite
- Slowbroite
- Steelixite
- Glalieite
- Sceptilite
- Blazikinite
- Swampertite
- Sableyeite
- Altariatite
- Sharpedoite
- Camerupite
- Salamencite
- Metagrossite
- Latiosite
- Latiasite
- Lopunnyite
- Galladite
- Audinite
- Diancieite

Comment: You cannot get the OR/AS mega stones in X/Y. Infact, while playing OR/AS you can be challenged to a battle by a passerby, but if that passerby is in X/Y you can't use any OR/AS exclusive megastones/mega-evolutions, or pokemon that have a move that is only available in OR/AS (Example - Hi-Jump kick Lopunny)

Comment: @TrentHawkins That's the first I've heard about HJK lopunny not being allowed, but I know that new ORAS moves like precipice blades aren't able to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the only way to get megastones not available in your game is through trading.

Comment: it is always better if you can state your source for the information in your answer. Even if the source is your own personal experience its better to note that is the case.